# Express session not setting cookie in browser

Tags: node.js

I'm learning express js and i'm using express-session npm package and when it's not on the same origin  is not setting the cookie in the browser. Can someone helps me with this issue, Thanks alot for your help

```
//backend
const express = require("express");
const session = require("express-session");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
    methods: ["GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE"],
    credentials: true,
  })
);
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "Secret tut",
    name: "tutorial",
    cookie: {
      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
      sameSite: "none",
      secure: true,
    },
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false,
  })
);

app.get("/:name", (req, res) => {
  const { name } = req.params;
  try {
    if (req.session.auth) {
      return res.send({ msg: `Hello ${req.session.auth}` });
    } else {
      req.session.auth = name;
      return res.send({ msg: `Helloo ${req.session.auth}` });
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return res.send(`Error found ${err}`);
  }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Started"));
```

```
       //frontend
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/myparam", {
        method: "GET",
        credentials: "include",
        mode: "cors",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      }).then((data) => console.log(data))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```